# Subtract column value of given row from all other rows

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to select `agg_cost` for a given `id`, and subtract that from all other rows. Then split the result into two columns: `downstream` for negative, `upstream` for positive results. I would like to generate a separate table for each subtraction.

Sample table data:

| agg_cost | id |
| --- | --- |
| 351.2267005 | 2.1 |
| 3444.240963 | 2.2 |
| 13337.39965 | 2.3 |
| 24618.73032 | 2.4 |
| 29523.72328 | 2.5 |
| 50051.75197 | 1.8 |
| 72884.10893 | 1.9 |
| 139114.7436 | 3.1 |
| 0 | origin |

Example calculation for given `id = 2.5`:

- origin =  2.5 (29523.723) - origin (0) = 29523.723
- 2.1 = 2.5 (29523.723) - 2.1 (351.226) = 29172.49658
- ... etc.

Desired result:

| id 2.5 | Upstream | Downstream |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id |  |  |
| origin | 29523.72328 |  |
| 2.1 | 29172.49658 |  |
| 2.2 | 26079.48231 |  |
| 2.3 | 16186.32363 |  |
| 2.4 | 4904.992963 |  |
| 1.8 |  | -20528.0287 |
| 1.9 |  | -43360.38565 |
| 3.1 |  | -109591.0203 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
     , CASE WHEN diff >= 0 THEN diff END AS upstream
     , CASE WHEN diff <  0 THEN diff END AS downstream
FROM  (
   SELECT t.id, s.agg_cost - t.agg_cost AS diff
   FROM   tbl t
   JOIN   tbl s ON s.id = '2.5'
               AND s.id <> t.id
   ) sub
ORDER  BY diff DESC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PkMbVKlb)

You might just go with a single result column (`diff` in the subquery). After splitting in two, I fill in `null` for the missing value. (`CASE` defaults to `null` when `ELSE` is missing.)

Assuming all columns `NOT NULL`, or you may have to do more.